# How can I "delete forever" all messages in Gmail's trash that match a search string?

Tags: gmail

I want to delete several thousand messages in Gmail's trash, but not all the messages in the trash. I can search to find the messages, but I can't find a way to delete them forever in bulk. This is what I'm doing:

1. Search for in:trash "text I know the messages contain"
2. Select all messages
3. Click on "Select all messages that match this search"

At that point, I'm told "All messages in this search are selected." I'm not told how many messages this is, so I don't know if it's really selected all the messages in the trash that match my search string. Assuming the right messages have been selected, I now want to delete them forever, but there's no option for that.

To reiterate, I only want to permanently delete the messages in the trash matching my search, so emptying the trash isn't an option.

Comment: Can you add a temporary label "trash" to ALL messages in bin, move them out of bin (now bin is empty, all bin emails are labelled as trash), and then search as in your question, delete only those, double check it back in trash that ONLY those messages are there the one you want to delete, once confirmed, empty trash. Then delete the messages labelled as Trash, to move them back to trash.

Comment: I haven't tried that, and it seems like it might work, but isn't there a direct way to permanently delete only the subset of email in the trash I want to get rid of?